# MySQL Bug required remedy : [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-'

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, myisam

We have a master & multiple slave replication in our production environment. At first, I found this error in the mysql error log on the master and later on the  slave. As for all the replication, the databases are fine, and slave updates are working well. Noevertheless, this error appears in the mysql error log. I just googled and checked. It's a bug.

Will it have any impact on the databases, as we had multiple db instances which is replicating master & multiple slave architecture?

Error Log :

```
111116 10:47:57 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3d6f_122a#P#p7'
111116 10:47:57 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p8'
111116 10:47:57 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p9'
111116 10:47:57 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p10'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p1'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p2'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p3'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p4'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p5'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p6'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p7'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p8'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p9'
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p10'
111116 10:48:46 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p1'
111116 10:48:46 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p2'
111116 10:48:46 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p3'
111116 10:48:46 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p4'
.....................................................................................;
```

Our error is in warning state. But as i googled and i can see the tag [error] state also:

```
[ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 't1#p#p4'
[ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 't1#p#p2'
[ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 't1#p#p2'
```

- I had a multiple Db instances around 70 & thousands of tables. What will be the query to trace out the particular table among multiple instances ?

  - Did any one faced this bug & solved the issue. I guess soon all my slaves will catch up this problem. What will be the impact in the production environment...?
- Will enabling the innodb_lock_monitor cause many of these messages to be printed out!
  create table innodb_lock_monitor(a int)engine=innodb; If so we handnt enabled. I had also seen in the innodb engine status. no sign of identity related to error/ warning.
- "Do you start MySQL server with database created in previous version?" but i hadnt done it. It is running in the version 5.1.39
- No plugins had been upgraded. So what could be root cause and remedy for this error/ bug..?

Answer (score 3):

There is the presence of a bug in this case for two reasons:

```
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p1' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p2' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p3' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p4' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p5' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p6' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p7' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p8' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p9' 
111116 10:48:29 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-3z8g_122a#P#p10'
```

**REASON #1** : Any table starting with `#sql` is a temp table. If these tables are still present in any database folder and the datetime stamp, simply delete them.

**REASON #2** : Look carefully at the suffix of each table. `#P#p?` resembles a partition tag. This would indicate an attempt to create a temp table using partitiions. That's sounds insane. [There was bug report on this back in Feb 16, 2006 for MySQL 5.1.7-beta (closed Mar 15, 2006)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17497). The bug report is based on trying to do this manually. Is mysql attempting to do this internally ?

IMHO I would upgrade mysql away from MySQL 5.1 up to MySQL 5.5